# Select2, how to format the element of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, jquery-select2

I have read the official API document but I don't really get it.

```
   function format(state) {
            if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
            return "<img class='flag' src='images/flags/" + state.id.toLowerCase() + ".png'/>" + state.text;
        }
        $("#e4").select2({
            formatResult: format,
            formatSelection: format
        });
```

Here are the codes from select2 about how to format an element.

However, I don't really understand the meaning of `format(state)` What does this `state` mean exactly?

---

I have a dropdown (data from an associative array, user_id=>username), now I want to format the dropdown result element so user can not only choose the username, but also they can see the user's avatar beside the username.

here are some of my codes... **but it doesn't work.**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#s2id2").select2({
            formatResult: function(){return "<img width='25px' height='25px' src='<?php echo $avatar;?>'/>" + "<?php echo $friend->username;?>";},
            formatSelection: function(){return "<img width='25px' height='25px' src='<?php echo $avatar;?>'/>" + "<?php echo $friend->username;?>";},
        });
});
</script>
```

Again, the structure of my data is "`user_id=>username`"...Any ideas?

Comment: I believe `state` is just a variable since the code is showing images in a folder named `flags`.  I assume the user is selecting a State and the result is an image of the Flag of that particular State

Comment: You could also take a look at this Yii extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2.

Comment: @VIDesignz Thanks for your reply. But I still don't get how to write the format code. For example, what variable should I use in my code? :-)

Comment: @jborch thanks! I already read that but in my case i need to load avatar from database so I can't use that format...

Comment: First, I would take off the comma `,` after the formatSelection function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out i gave up using the javascript, instead, i use the following function:

```
foreach($friends as $friend){
$avatar = Profile::model()->findByPk($friend)->avatar;
array_push_assoc($list,$friend2->sender,"<img width='20px;' height='20px;' style='float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;' src='".$avatar2."'/>".$friend2->senderx->username);
}
```